# How to dynamically create text box when we click on a link using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

- I have a problem to show **INPUT** field when do some action.

  - I have BUTTON (Click here) as soon as user made a click event on button i wanted to show input field
  - I have done this by using jQuery.

  Can any one help me in Angular.js

Comment: you can try the angular directive as mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423152/create-dynamic-textbox-using-angular-directive

Comment: Try too ad `ng-show="someVariable"` to your TextBox and set an `ng-click="OnLinkClicked()"` on your link and set `someVariable = true` in your `OnLinkClicked`

Comment: please feedback bu selecting right answer

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.boxShow = false;
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <a href="#" ng-click="boxShow=!boxShow">show box</a>

        <div ng-show="boxShow">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50">text</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxwjpmaa/1/

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
 <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openTextBox();">Click Me To open text box</div>
 <div ng-show="openTextBox == true">
   <input type="text"/>
 </div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
 $scope.openTextBox = function () {
     $scope.openTextBox = true;
 }
```

please don't take scope variables and function names same 
example here

```
 $scope.openTextBox = function () {
   $scope.openTextBox = true;
   }
```

//this is not correct as per angular documentation because scope.openTextBox name already assigned to scope function,again its assigning scope variable "$scope.openTextBox = true" here u will get errors when ever u clicked div second time" TypeError: boolean is not a function" it will throw this error.so please dont use which is already assigned scope function dont assign scope variable

see this fiddle url : https://jsfiddle.net/veerendrakumarfiddle/bxwjpmaa/2/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ol>
<li ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <input type="text" ng-model="element.value"/>
    </li>
</ol>
<br/>
<b>Click here to add Textbox:</b><br/><input type="button" value="New Item" ng-click="newItem()"/>
<br/>
<br/>

<b>Click here to see ng-model value:</b><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="show(elements)">

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 var counter=0;
    $scope.elements = [ {id:counter, value : ''} ];

    $scope.newItem = function(){
        counter++;
        $scope.elements.push(  { id:counter,value:''} );
        
    }
    
    $scope.show=function(elements)
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(elements));
        
    }
  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```